# Register an application for lubuntu's "Run" dialog

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, menu, dialog

I have built an application from source. Now I want to be able to start that application using lubuntu's Run dialog (the one opened via Alt-F2, Super+R or directly from the "start" menu). But the Run dialog does not find this application, despite it being in `$PATH`. Starting the application from terminal emulators (lxterminal etc.) works fine.

Does the Run dialog look for entries similar to the .desktop entries for the "start" menu? How can I customize what applications it finds?

Currently I'm using lubuntu 15.10, but I'm interested in the answer for lubuntu 16.04 as well.

Comment: How did you add your path?  And did you restart your session before trying it?

Comment: @Dorian I added it to .bashrc, but I'll try .profile now as well. Yes, I've restarted my session/computer after adding to `$PATH`.

Comment: @Dorian D'oh the Run dialog finds it when I add it to `$PATH` via .profile. Kind of obvious, with hindsight.

Comment: Yes that's why wanted to ask first before posting an answer. DE's don't process .bashrc, but they do process .profile.

Comment: @Dorian Please, if you like, you can still post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop environments don't process the .bashrc file.

In order for you to have the path available to the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run dialog, you need to edit your `~/.profile` file, as a regular user, `sudo` is not required.  You can use any editor such as `nano` or `gedit`.

Add the following line to the bottom of the `.profile` file:

`PATH="/path/to/folder:$PATH"`

Alternatively, if you have a line such as the one below:

`PATH:"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/treedev/lib/Qt/bin"`

You can add your path to that following the same convention of paths being separated by a colon.  But it's easier to do the first way so that you can spot your own edit easier and remove it in the future if need be.

After saving and closing, restart your session by logging out and back in, or in terminal, type `source ~/.profile` for changes to take effect.